# can't run my .pbk file

Tags: windows-7, vpn

When I double click on my connection.pbk it's was open by Adobe PixelBender and I don't know how can I fix that.

Answer (score 2):

easy solution:
right click on the file and chose open with, then find rasphone.exe from system32 folder and click OK.

enjoy

Comment: What is rasphone.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Some users have problems opening .pbk (vpn) files in Windows 7. If you have Adobe Pixel Bender then the .pbk files will open using the Adobe Pixel Bender. If you still want to open pbk files as VPN connection (with Windows Remote Access Phonebook), please follow the steps below:

1. Launch Notepad.
2. Copy the following content into Notepad.

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.pbk] @="pbkfile"
3. Save to Desktop with the name .pkb.reg
4. Launch the saved file from Desktop to modify the registry to change the file association.

If the issue still occurs, please follow the steps below:

1. Launch Notepad.
2. Copy the following content into Notepad.

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pbkfile] @="Dial-Up
   >   Phonebook"
   >   "FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
   >   00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
   >   32,00,5c,00,72,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,6c,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,\
   >   00,2d,00,33,00,35,00,33,00,00,00
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pbkfile\DefaultIcon]
   >   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
   >   00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,61,00,\
   >   73,00,64,00,6c,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,36,00,32,\
   >   00,00,00
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pbkfile\Shell]
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pbkfile\Shell\open]
   >
   > [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pbkfile\Shell\open\command]
   >   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
   >   00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,61,00,\
   >   73,00,70,00,68,00,6f,00,6e,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,66,\
   >   00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00
3. Save to Desktop with the name .pkb.reg
4. Launch the saved file from Desktop to modify the registry to change the file association.

Comment: The Shell open command listed here by @Nelly converted to readable Unicode string is: `%SystemRoot%\system32\rasphone.exe -f "%1"` similar to answer suggested by @mehrzad.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just had this problem too, I installed Adobe pixel bender tool and .pbk vpn connection file got associated to it,

---

- I went to registry and pushed ctrl+f and searched pbk in registry
- I found "pbk opens with:Adobe pixel bender" entry and the program associated to it was Adobe pixel bender I deleted the entry(by the way you have to push ctrl+f several times until you reach this entry.)
- then after I closed regedit.exe I right clicked on the file and chose "Open whith" then "Choose default Program"
- now browse for the "rasphone.exe" file in System 32 and associate it to your file and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the wrong association with the file extension.

Open *Control Panel*.  Go to *Default Programs*.  Then *Set Associations*.  Find .pbk and change the application associated with it.